# How can I convert this function from php into javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, migration

My intent is to get a list of all day of the month/year that I choose. Besides that, I'll add extra html into the final result.

I created this php function, but noticed that it's better, because I'll edit it in the html, if I do it on my  tag.

The code list all days and name of week days of the month/year that I send (I also convert the language result).

I tried but couldn't even produce a nice base to start, I'm troubled to find a way to replicate the same idea using javascript.

my php function

```
function getDays($month = 0, $year = 0){
    $list = array();
    $month = $month == 0 ? (int)date('m') : $month;
    $year = $year == 0 ? (int)date('Y') : $year;
    $weekName = ['Mon' => 'Seg', 'Tue' => 'Ter', 'Wed' => 'Qua', 'Thu' => 'Qui', 'Fri' => 'Sex', 'Sat' => 'Sáb', 'Sun' => 'Dom'];

    for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
    {
        $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);
        if (date('m', $time)==$month) {
            $list[]= date('d', $time) . ' | ' . $weekName[date('D', $time)].'.';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($list);
}
```

Comment: Come on. Just remove all that `$` and search the js api equivalents of `array()` , `date()`, `mktime()` and you are done

Comment: This seems like a relatively straight-forward one-to-one conversion, which would probably return the list at the end instead of echoing it. Is there any part in particular that's troubling you? "I don't know how to do it" isn't all that helpful

Comment: I think you could benefit from a date library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I was trying to achiv this without a lib. I can always do a $.ajax and get the content of the php function. So I'm trying to a one-to-one conversion. the problem lies on the usability of mktime and date functions. I imagined that for that I would need moment.js, but I'm asking if someone can help with this without the need of a lib

Comment: What is your resistance to using a (powerful and helpful) library?  You mentioned `$.ajax`, which means you're already using jQuery, which is, yup, a library

Comment: @PatrickQ not against using a library, just that get a lib or doing an ajax call is kinda of the same, no?

Comment: In what way do you consider them to be the same? What do you see as the negative of using something like moment.js?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service. Post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Interesting how ppl don't understand something and just downvote cuz their are lazy to do something else besides using libs...

Comment: @PatrickQ - in this case using moment would be crazy overkill. Just using `(i+idx)%7` was enough where i is the daynumber of the 1st of the month

Comment: @mplungjan For someone (OP) who "couldn't even produce a nice base to start", I'm not sure I'd call it overkill.  Sure, for an advanced developer who can whip up an optimized solution quickly, there's no need.  But if your choice is between using Moment or waiting a few days for random people on the internet to give you an answer, then I think Moment is at least worth _considering_. And that's all I wanted OP to do, consider it. But I couldn't even get any reasoning for the objection to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing you did come up with an answer, here is an optimised version since there is no need to create an array each time and no need for a new date inside the loop. Also months start at 0:

```js
var dias = ['Sun-Dom', 'Mon-Seg', 'Tue-Ter', 'Wed-Qua', 'Thu=Qui', 'Fri-Sex', 'Sat-Sab'];

function getDays(year, month) {
  month--; // JS months start at 0
  var dSta = new Date(year, month, 1);
  var dEnd = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
  var ret = [];
  var idx = dSta.getDay()-1; // 0th day
  for (var i = dSta.getDate(), end = dEnd.getDate(); i <= end; i++) {
    ret.push(i + ' - ' + dias[(i+idx)%7]);
  }
  return ret;
}
console.log(getDays(2018,2)); // 2 = Feb which is month 1 in JS
console.log(getDays(2020,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little twist, the following get the job done...

```
function getDays(year, month)
{
    var dias = ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'];
    var dSta = new Date(year,month,1);
    var dEnd = new Date(year,month+1,0);
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = dSta.getDate(); i <= dEnd .getDate();i++)
    {
        ret.push(i + ' - ' + dias[new Date(year, month, i).getDay()]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

After that, just call

```
console.log(getDays(2018,2));
```